# Getting CSV data only at specific intervals using python

Tags: python

I have tick data being stored into a csv file. From this file, I am converting it to a 5 min data (ohlc). Stock exchange opens at 10:00 am and closes at 23:55 hrs. 
Although there are no records in CSV files when exchange is closed, Pyhon is creating empty rows. How do I get python to start recoding data only when the exchange is open between 10 Am to 23:50 Pm? Im new to coding and at wits end to figure this out. Appreciate any help out there.

[You can see empty rows before exchange opening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw1wO.jpg)

we are new to python and this is minimal code we have managed to write.

```
import pandas as pd

#Input files needed for pair
data_frame1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Pair_Trade\\COPPER19FEBFUT.csv', names= 
['Symbol', 'Date_Time', 'Price', 'Bucket'],index_col=1, parse_dates=True)
data_frame2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Pair_Trade\\ZINC19FEBFUT.csv', names= 
['Symbol', 'Date_Time', 'Price', 'Bucket'],index_col=1, parse_dates=True)

#Close price calculation for 5min TF
data_close1 = data_frame1['Price'].resample('5Min').ohlc()
data_close2 = data_frame2['Price'].resample('5Min').ohlc()

pair_data=pd.concat([data_close1['close'], data_close2['close']], axis = 1)
pair_data.columns=['COPPER','ZINC']

#Calculation Ratio
pair_data['Ratio'] = round(pair_data['COPPER']/ pair_data['ZINC'],4)

#Writing to csv
pair_data.to_csv('C:\\Pair_trade\\result.csv', index = True, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')


spread = data_close1['close']/ data_close2['close']
spread.name = 'Ratio'
spread_mean=spread.mean()
spread_std=spread.std()

display(pair_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either:

- drop your NA values before sending it to your csv:

  ```
  pair_data.dropna(how='all').to_csv('C:\\Pair_trade\\result.csv',
                                      index = True, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
  ```
- select the value you want with between_time

  ```
  pair_data.between_time('10:00','23:55').to_csv('C:\\Pair_trade\\result.csv',
                                      index = True, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
  ```

Comment: Jimkoons, Sir, Thanks for your very kind assistance. Appreciate it. I will run the code and check output in the morning and give you feed back. Thank you again!